# Maximum Scale-Out of Azure Websites

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

While studying the [Azure Web Sites Pricing Details](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/web-sites/), one limitation got me thinking.

Even the "Standard" tier comes with an artificial limit of 10 for *Scale-Out (max instances)*

Let's say you wanted to start a business that involves hosting of thousands of specialized sites for customers, the limitation of 10 instances would prevent further growth of your business at some point.

Could someone (from the Azure Team perhaps) explain the reasoning for this limitation?

Comment: Create 10 sites with the same deployment package and scale them to 10 and you got 100 instances.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These quotas are there to prevent people from making costly mistakes.  Many of these can be increased simply by contacting Azure support.  This Microsoft blog post explains how: http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/06/04/azure-limits-quotas-increase-requests/